# cloudsql and appengine datastore: cursor vs. offset and limit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'd like to understand if google cloudsql uses datastore as it's data storage.

So I loaded a google cloudsql table with over 100K records

Then I tried a query with `LIMIT 100000,10` vs. `LIMIT 0,10`

See http://cloudsql.website-showcase.appspot.com/?pagesize=10&offset=100000 
vs. http://cloudsql.website-showcase.appspot.com/?pagesize=10&offset=0

The performance seems to be the same.  Does this mean that cloudsql has an efficient way to use datastore for limit and offset OR does cloudsql NOT use datastore OR is 100K records too small a case to judge performance?

An additional question is if cloudsql is using datastore bigtable to implement limit and offset.  Is it doing it efficiently?  Or is it scanning all records and only returning the limit part?  (This is what the documentation says that limit and offset usage does in the datastore query case.  Which is not recommended.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No. The whole point of [CloudSQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/introduction) is that it isn't using the datastore:

> Google Cloud SQL is, simply put, a MySQL instance that lives in the cloud.

Comment: thanks Daniel.   app engine is built to scale well automatically .    is cloud sql also built to scale automatically or do i have to increase the machine size manually etc as demand increases